# How to save the size preferences of the customer in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I need to create a module in which I need to save the size preferences for the customer. If a customer chooses the a specific size(for e.g:XL) filer for a category then on all the subsequent visits to that category, only the products of the selected size must be displayed and also when the customer navigates to any other category then also he must see only the product of the selected size from the previous category. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so do you want to something like this, based on customer selection, that size product only show into the entire store.

Comment: yes, after the selection of size, the guest customer will see the products of that size only for all the categories.